# How to store a very small number

Tags: c#

I have a formula to calculate weights of some numbers in C#. I have 9 weights. The sum of these weights is 1, so these are too small. 
For instance after calculating these weights, the result is something like below:

1/17, 1/17, 1/17, 1/17, 1/17, 1/17, 1/17, 1/17, 9/17

When I want to store these weights in a parameter with `double` type, the stored values will be:

0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0

The problem is that I need the exact value of these weights to use in another formula, and they are too important in that formula. The sum of them should be 1.

What can I do for solving this problem?

Comment: Maybe you should use decimal instead.

Comment: The rational number 1/17 won't be 0.0 as a double. But writing `1/17` in your code results in `0` because it uses integer arithmetic.

Comment: to explain what Dirk mentioned: 1/17 = 0 but 1/17.0 = 0.05882

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Using `decimal` would be an option if the fraction they have is exactly representable in decimal floating-point. Which it isn't. `1d/17d*17` in PowerShell yields `1.0000000000000000000000000004`, which obviously is not quite 1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First，you should not calculate the exact value using `1/17`; the compiler consider it as int 0 then converts the int 0 to double 0.0. You can code like this: `1.0/17.0` or `1/(double)17`.

Second, if you want the sum of the values to be 1, you could use `Math.Round(1.0/17*10000)
/10000` to get the exact decimal with five numbers after the dot.

Comment: The second part of your answer is wrong: Sum(roundings) != rounding(sum)

Comment: Dear Askolein you are right, but sum of them is so close to 1. That is why i used that.

Answer (score 12):

[A `double` is perfectly capable of storing *about* `1/17`.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6VkEOD) It will not be able to do so with perfect accuracy and precision. But maybe that is enough for you. Your mistake probably was to use integer division. Try `1.0/17.0`.

Only a data type that can store a fraction of the form `a/b` could exactly store `1/17`. Any finite precision number cannot (and as computer memory is finite, all numbers are finite precision).

Let's ask the SMT Solver Z3 to provide an example where `1.0/divisor*divisor != 0.0`. [An example for floats is](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4S8P9):

```
    float divisor = (float)(int)(1.296875 * 64);
    Console.WriteLine(divisor); //83
    Console.WriteLine(1.0f/divisor*divisor == 1.0); //False
```

Found using the following [SMTlib input with Z3 online](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/ji7v):

```
(set-logic QF_FPA)    

(declare-const x (_ FP 8 24))
(declare-const divisor (_ FP 8 24))
(declare-const r1 (_ FP 8 24))
(declare-const r2 (_ FP 8 24))

(assert (and 
    (not (or (= x (as NaN (_ FP 8 24))) (= x (as plusInfinity (_ FP 8 24))) (= x (as minusInfinity (_ FP 8 24)))))
    (not (or (= divisor (as NaN (_ FP 8 24))) (= divisor (as plusInfinity (_ FP 8 24))) (= divisor (as minusInfinity (_ FP 8 24)))))
    (not (or (= r1 (as NaN (_ FP 8 24))) (= r1 (as plusInfinity (_ FP 8 24))) (= r1 (as minusInfinity (_ FP 8 24)))))
    (not (or (= r2 (as NaN (_ FP 8 24))) (= r2 (as plusInfinity (_ FP 8 24))) (= r2 (as minusInfinity (_ FP 8 24)))))
    (> divisor ((_ asFloat 8 24) roundTowardZero 2.0 0))
    (< divisor ((_ asFloat 8 24) roundTowardZero 100.0 0))
    (== divisor (roundToIntegral roundTowardZero divisor))
    (= x ((_ asFloat 8 24) roundTowardZero 1.0 0))
    (= r1 (/ roundNearestTiesToEven x divisor))
    (= r2 (* roundNearestTiesToEven r1 divisor))
    (not (== r2 ((_ asFloat 8 24) roundTowardZero 1.0 0)))
))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Z3 has bit-precise reasoning over IEEE floats. The resulting model is:

```
(model 
  (define-fun r2 () (_ FP 8 24)
    (as +1.99999988079071044921875p-1 (_ FP 8 24)))
  (define-fun divisor () (_ FP 8 24)
    (as +1.296875p6 (_ FP 8 24)))
  (define-fun x () (_ FP 8 24)
    (as +1p0 (_ FP 8 24)))
  (define-fun r1 () (_ FP 8 24)
    (as +1.54216861724853515625p-7 (_ FP 8 24)))
)
```

Comment: Why not a decimal? I tried in linqpad and 1/17 is the same for both decimal and double, but why chose one over the other?

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos because neither of those values represent 1/17 exactly. `1/17.0*17.0` is likely not exactly `1.0`. If it is, then by rounding accident.

Comment: OK, turns out for 17 the division-multiplication round-trip is exact but that is not guaranteed in general.

Comment: Well, i think i found my own answer... It seems that `c` being decimal and `f` being double, both are defined as `1/17`, `(c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c).Dump()` produces `1,0000000000000000000000000004` while `(f+f+f+f+f+f+f+f+f+f+f+f+f+f+f+f+f).Dump();` produces `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Without using rational numbers, an exact representation of 1/17 is going to be difficult to achieve. `decimal` will give you a higher precision representation than will `double`.